# How do I disable facebook's ?brand_redir and open new page without extra piece of URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, redirect

I'm trying to disable facebook's redirection to another country page by restructuring its URL.
An example would be - you're trying to open https://www.facebook.com/VisaID/ but if you're accessing the page from another country, you're going to be redirected to the closes page based on your geolocation (I guess). In my case, it's https://www.facebook.com/VisaCzechRepublic/?brand_redir=272936492828277 and I want to prevent this.

I tried to write a piece of code to solve this, however, when I try to reload the page with restructured URL it somehow adds extra window.location.hostname and window.location.pathname resulting in an absolute mess and breaking the page...
result = https://www.facebook.com/VisaCzechRepublic/www.facebook.com/272936492828277/?brand_redir=DISABLE

Code I used:

```
//Split URL to get FB ID
var brand = window.location.search;
brand = brand.split("=");
brandId = brand[1];

//Create new URL
//First facebook.com
//Second Page ID
//Third add ?brand_redir=DISABLE at the end
url = window.location.hostname + "/" + brandId + "/" + "?brand_redir=DISABLE";

//Open rearranged URL
window.open(url)
```

I expected Chrome to open a new URL exactly as is saved in the `url` being https://www.facebook.com/272936492828277/?brand_redir=DISABLE

but it somehow sneaks in extra https://www.facebook.com/VisaCzechRepublic/ and only after that ads the `url` I want.
Thanks a ton for any advice!

Comment: window.location.hostname doesn't start with protocol. So window.open will treat it as a relative redirect instead of an absolutely.

Comment: @WizKid Thanks! That was it :)